# Selecting multiple documents using a criteria in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am new to mongodb and mongoid.  I am used to ActiveRecord/mysql in Ruby
on Rails so pardon my ignorance.

In ActiveRecord world if I want to search for all records meeting a certain
criteria (students from a specific zipcode), I could use

```
students = Student.where(zipcode: "12345")
```

and this would return an array of students.

Using Mongoid, if I query

```
Student.all.where(zipcode: "12345")
```

it just returns a criteria and I have to use an iterator like

```
students = []
Student.all.where(zipcode: "12345").each  { |s|  students << s }
```

Is there a better way to do a Mongoid /Mongo query to get all the documents
meeting the search criteria without using the ruby iterators (.each) ?

I have been referring to the mongoid document from
https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-queries/

and couldn't find an example to get all the documents in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You're being fooled by the console if you think:

```
students = Student.where(zipcode: "12345")
```

gives you an array of `Student`s in `students`. That actually gives you a relation object in `students` but the relation's `inspect` (which is called by the console) will load the records from the database behind your back; similarly, as soon as you try to do anything array-ish with a relation, it will load records from the database.

Mongoid's `where` behaves the same but it won't necessary resolve to model instances in all the same cases that an ActiveRecord relation will.

The easiest thing to do (with both ActiveRecord and Mongoid) is to call `to_a` on the relation/criteria if you really want an array:

```
# ActiveRecord
students = Student.where(zipcode: "12345")      # students is a relation
students = Student.where(zipcode: "12345").all  # students is still a relation
students = Student.where(zipcode: "12345").to_a # students is now a real array

# Mongoid
students = Student.where(zipcode: "12345")      # students is a criteria
students = Student.where(zipcode: "12345").all  # students is still a criteria
students = Student.where(zipcode: "12345").to_a # students is now a real array
```

In both cases, if you want an array then just say so using `to_a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation - it makes sense now. Also just learned that Student.where(...) returns a criteria and no query is done until it's assigned to a variable or iterated over.